# Is riding an electric scooter on pavement not tolerated in London?

Tags: london

In the UK the law says that you are not allowed to ride an [electric kick scooter](http://www.evoscooters.co.uk/electric-folding-scooters/all-new-evo-powerboard-electric-scooter-300w-9-tyres-light-compact.html) on pavement.

In practice, would you get fined for that or is it 'tolerated' ?

Comment: The law say no.  Why disobey it?

Comment: If I had a penny for every time I was almost knocked off by some goofball riding his bike on the pavement because it's "tolerated"...

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced this is either on-topic or actually answerable in a useful fashion. I'm voting to close as off-topic, if you can edit the question to be on-topic I suggest making the scope less broad as well (i.e. is there a particular reason you're asking, or a particular place you're likely to be going in London).

Comment: (hover board owner): You will get a caution the first time and fined after that.  But it's off topic here, sorry.

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's both a mode of transport and an "is X tolerated in Y location" question, both of which are on topic. Also - London steets are narrow and crowded, Londoners are intolerant of things that might be in the way and London traffic is merciless. One kid was already [killed using one in December](http://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2015/dec/11/hoverboard-death-in-london-believed-to-be-first-involving-swegway) after being hit by a bus and I've heard various press reports of people being shoved off them (sometimes then stolen)

Comment: London pavements are also narrow and crowded and trying to ride a motorised vehicle on them will make people dislike you very much.